# regex.h header not found or breaking the file

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to use regular expression for a project in C but it seems like it's not working or I'm maybe missing something.

When I try to `#include <regex.h>` it says `Cannot open source file 'regex.h'`.

When I try to `#include <regex>` it breaks my size_t data type and makes all my function calls not allowed in a constant expressions.

What do I need to make it work using Visual Studio as an environment, maybe there is an easier way to use regular expressions in C

Comment: `regex.h` is a POSIX (i.e. Unix, Linux or macOS) specific header file. To use regular expressions in Windows using MSVC you need to find a portable library to use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the answer, it's much clear to me now, can you maybe refer me a link of such libray in windows, I will of course search on my side too

Comment: For me, regular expressions is usually the last solution I try, as I think most problems could be solved without adding the complexity of them (for almost every problem there usually are other, better and definitely simpler solutions). So I don't use them much. And I've never used it on Windows, so have no idea of libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude after few moments of thinking I took the decision to do it myself, I don't think regex is necessary, I will simply use some if/else or even switch/case statement for my needs, thanks for your time and have a great day